# How to solve error of parsing YAML configuration in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to solve while parsing a block mapping error for use Spring Boot with Eureka server configuration

```
while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 5, column 3:
      application:
      ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
 in 'reader', line 15, column 4:
       hikari:
```

[image: image in application.yml]

Comment: Don't post code as image, post as text instead

Comment: ok nikolai thank for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indention is not correct.

hikari is one space too much to the right.